# Game Loop for Racket

Tags: loops, racket, program-entry-point, cycle

I am working on a very basic memory game in RACKET that presents the user with 7 random numbers from 1 to 10 and asks them to type in the numbers in the same order.  I can get this to work once but I want it to continually run until the user exits out.  (Repeat MAIN PROGRAM) Any ideas on how to accomplish this???

```
(require math/base)

; =======================================
; Functions
; =======================================
; set essentially constants
(define lowerLimit 1)
(define upperLimit 11)
(define amount 7)


; builds a list with random integers between lowerLimit and upperLimit
(define (buildSimon x L)
  (cond [(= x 0) L]
        [else (buildSimon (- x 1) (cons (random-integer lowerLimit upperLimit) L))]))

; adds element to back of the list
(define (addBack L e)
  (if (null? L)
      (list e)
      (cons (first L) (addBack (rest L) e))))

; gets input from user and builds list
(define (getInput n x L)
  (cond [(= n 1) (addBack L x)]
        [else (getInput (- n 1) (read) (addBack L x))]))

; =======================================
; Main program below here
; =======================================
; Generate new random number sequence
(printf "Simon says: ")
(define sequence (buildSimon amount (list)))
(display sequence) (newline)
(printf "== Memorize and guess ==\n")
(printf "== Type 'go' and hit enter to guess ==\n")
(read)

; Add spacing to hide numbers
(printf "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")
(printf "== Type the numbers in order as they appeared. ==\n")
(printf "== Hit ENTER in between each number. ==\n")

; Gather input for comparison
(define answer (getInput amount (read) (list)))

; Do comparison
(if (equal? sequence answer)
    (printf "Correct! Congratulations on your perfect memory.\n")
    (printf "Wrong! I'm sorry your memory has failed you.\n"))
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function which contains all of your main code, with the last line of the function recursively calling itself.